# Determining datatype of input parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to **determine the datatype** of input parameter in a pl_sql function like we have **instanceof** in java. I have tried using dump function but it can be used in the query only.

Comment: Not sure I follow... you declare the datatype in the function specification. Within the function it will have that datatype, so are you trying to find out what type it was in the call, before it was maybe implicitly converted to the input parameter type? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to write a generic getter for all the input parameters. like if the input parameter is varchar2 then i can call getter for Varchar2.

Comment: SQL doesn't work like that - it's a strongly-typed language; you have to define the datatype for each parameter when you define the function. I don't know what you have in mind, but I don't think it would be particularly useful in PL/SQL.

Comment: I am generating query dynamically in a function returning varchar2 so to avoid parsing time I want to use the getters for IN parameters and if i try to write getter for each parameter then code will become lengthy.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no facility for dynamic typing of procedure arguments in PL/SQL.  If you come up with something else I'm sure that many of us would be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: @BobJarvis - there's the [`anydata` type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i107578), but I'm not sure it helps much. You still need to refer to all the parameters by name at some point so this approach seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

From comments it seems like you want to build a dynamic query string by looping over the input parameters, presumably to build up the `where` clause without having to type it in manually. That seems like it'll make maintenance and understanding harder for not much benefit.

But, as an exercise, you *could* loop over the parameter definitions from the `user_arguments` view. The trouble is you can't get the actual parameter *values* without naming them, and if you did then the data type would only matter if you were putting the values into the dynamic string directly (which you can't really do in a loop) rather than as bind variables, which would be a bad thing to do anyway. And if you're using bind variable then you don't need to know the data type.

So for my own amusement mostly, if I have a table with various data types:

```
create table t42(col1 varchar2(10), col2 number, col3 date);
insert into t42 values ('data', 42, trunc(sysdate));
```

... and a function where the parameter names match the table column names, then you can build a dynamic string with bind variables:

```
create function f42(col1 t42.col1%type, col2 t42.col2%type,
    col3 t42.col3%type)
return varchar2 is
    str varchar(4000);
    result t42.col1%type;
    have_where boolean := false;
begin
    str := 'select col1 from t42';
    for r in (
        select argument_name, data_type
        from user_arguments
        where object_name = 'F42'
        and position > 0 -- to account for return type
        order by position
    ) loop
        if not have_where then
            have_where := true;
            str := str || ' where ';
        else
            str := str || ' and ';
        end if;
        str := str || r.argument_name || ' = :' || r.argument_name;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line(str);

    execute immediate str into result using col1, col2, col3;
    return result;
end;
/
```

Which I can then call from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var rc varchar2(10);
SQL> exec :rc := f42('data', 42, trunc(sysdate));

select col1 from t42 where COL1 = :COL1 and COL2 = :COL2 and COL3 = :COL3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

RC
--------------------------------
data
```

Obviously a very contrived example, but it would scale with more parameters, with only the `using` clause needing to list them all. I think. Which does **not** mean I think this is a good idea - just for fun...

You could do some manipulation within the loop based on data type if you wanted, by checking the `r.data_type` value:

```
        str := str || r.argument_name || ' = ';
        if r.data_type = 'DATE' then
            str := str || 'trunc(:' || r.argument_name || ')';
        else
            str := str || ':' || r.argument_name;
        end if;
```

... which you could then call without having to `trunc` the value in the call:

```
SQL> exec :rc := f42('data', 42, sysdate);

select col1 from t42 where COL1 = :COL1 and COL2 = :COL2 and COL3 = trunc(:COL3)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

RC
--------------------------------
data
```

... but other than that, you wouldn't need to know the type of each column in the dynamic string as the binding would take care of that anyway.